# Best practice using if guard statement with Angular promises

Tags: angularjs

Is the below the best way to use a if guard with angular promise?

```
function doIt(p) {
   var dfd = $q.defer();
   if (!p) {
      // this the best syntax to return the promise?
      dfd.resolve(true);
      return dfd.promise;
   }

   // whole bunch of code stuff with a resolve() and reject()

   // finally
   return dfd.promise;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this would be much cleaner

```
function doIt(p) {
    if (!p)
        return $q.when(true)
    else
        return someLongFunction()
}
```

or if you want to make it clear it is a guard

```
function doIt(p) {
    if (!p)
        return $q.when(true)

    return someLongFunction()
}
```

Comment: It can even be `return $q.when(!p || someLongFunction())`.

Comment: oh yes. that's definitely shorter. but as a guard clause pattern it would be nice to keep the first check separate, like in the 2nd code block. Cheers!